# keep the implicit import/export for ProjectA and manually import some types from ProjectA to ProjectB

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt3 "ProjectA" using typescript with implicit import/export for typechecks in VSCode.

This is great for this ProjectA because al my "*.d.ts" files located in the "types" folder are distributed globally to this project. That's what i wanted, I don't need to import manually my types for this project.

example of *.d.ts file : `type MyType = 'user' | 'admin'`

But, I want to use some of these types for another "ProjectB" located in another folder.
In this "ProjectB", I tried to import MyType with this line of code below. I want to import manually the types for this ProjectB from ProjectA :

`import type { MyType } from "@ProjectA/types/file.d.ts"`

This works when I put an export in *.d.ts of ProjectA types :
`export type MyType = 'user' | 'admin'` but In this case, the implicit import/export for ProjectA don't work anymore !!!

ProjectA tsconfig.json :

```
{
  // https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/typescript
  "extends": "./.nuxt/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

ProjectB tsconfig.json :

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strict": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "@ProjectA/*": [
                "../pathTo/ProjectA/*"
            ]
        },
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    }
}
```

Also, I tried to use these options of compilationOptions without success : "files", "include", "references"...

To sum up : I wan't to keep the implicit import/export for projectA (without 'export') and manually import some types from ProjectA to ProjectB (but I need to export my types...).

How can I reach that goal ?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT ANSWER (I found the misconfiguration).

In the ProjectA, the FileName.d.ts file looked like this :

```
type MyType = 'user' | 'admin'
```

But this .d.ts file should look like that :

```
declare global {
    type MyType = 'user' | 'admin'
}
export { MyType }
```

Now, it is possible to import types from ProjectA to ProjectB.
The index.d.ts file of ProjectB may look like this :

```
// import from ProjectA
export type { MyType } from "@ProjectA/types/FileName"

// then we can declare our ProjectB local types
declare global {
    type LocalProjectBType = 'otherUser' | 'otherAdmin'
}
```

With this configuration, we keep the global / implicit types for our two projects and we can share types from one project to another.